How do I fold a function over the bindings in a map in Isabelle?
What I want to be able to do is fold a function over the bindings in a map, and look up keys.
Coq has the FMap modules, is there a similar Isabelle theory module?
https://coq.inria.fr/doc/v8.19/stdlib/Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.html
("find" and "fold" are the functions I'm interested in.)
I've been looking through the HOL library, and can't find anything that seems applicable.The maps in Main have no way to do folding, and the AList and Mapping theories only supply a few functions. In particular, they seem to have no lookup functions.

So basically you want a list of pairs and not a mapping right? (Fold only makes sense if finite support and ordered)

An association list would be fine. I'm not interested in the order. What I want to do is add mappings from one map to another, but going through a function first. Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.fold can be conveniently used to do that.

@GlynWebster Could you expand your answer to include an example pair of input and output of the intended function?

I guess that https://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Library/Mapping.html#Mapping.lookup|const is what you want

Oh! It's right there. That is what I was looking for. "lookup" and "combine_with_key".  (Perhaps I was searching through the Isabelle library source code for "definition" with whole-word enabled, those are "lift_definition".)
